# Paged printing with javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

I have 4 divs that I want to print each one on a separate page. Is this possible if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a print stylesheet, if you don't already have one.  Set `media="print"` when including that stylesheet.  Among other things, add a class with the page break settings, such as:

```
.break-after
{
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

Then apply that style wherever you need a page break forced.

```
<div id="div1" class="break-after"></div>
<div id="div2" class="break-after"></div>
<div id="div3" class="break-after"></div>
<div id="div4" class="break-after"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the CSS `page-break-before:always` on each DIV. See [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-break-props) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [page breaks](http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks) in your print CSS.